# @ManyToOne as reference to other table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I'd like the security question in the account entity to "reference" one of the security questions in the SecurityQuestion table and not create a new one. Take the following:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue...
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private SecurityQuestion question;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class SecurityQuestion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue...
    private Long id;
    private String question;
    ...
}
```

When using Spring's form:select to select the security question for the account, it creates a new security question when I save the account entity. Note: The SecurityQuestion table is a list of predefined questions to display.

```
<form:select path="securityQuestion.question">
    <form:option value="" label="Select..."/>
    <form:options items="${questions}" />
</form:select>
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because `CascadeType.ALL` set and you lose somewhere `id` of `SecurityQuestion` (so, hibernate in order to `CascadeType.PERSIST` creates new entity).